# Why do I get an error when the pointer is not copied?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code throws an error. The error is at the delete[] pIntArray the error is  _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{

    int* pIntArray = new int[50];
    cout << "adding numbers to array ..." << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        pIntArray[i] = i + 10;
    }

    cout << "values in array: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        cout << "integer[" << i << "] = " << *(pIntArray++) << endl;

    }

    cout << "deleting dynamic memory ..." << endl;

    delete[] pIntArray;

    cout << "memory deleted." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but this does not. The only difference is that I am copying the pointer and incrementing the copy:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{

    int* pIntArray = new int[50];
    cout << "adding numbers to array ..." << endl;
    int* pCopy = pIntArray;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        pIntArray[i] = i + 10;
    }

    cout << "values in array: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        cout << "integer[" << i << "] = " << *(pCopy++) << endl;

    }

    cout << "deleting dynamic memory ..." << endl;

    delete[] pIntArray;

    cout << "memory deleted." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pointer you give to `delete[]` has to match the same pointer you got from `new[]`. In this case, you've incremented it in-between. This goes for regular `new`/`delete` and `malloc`/`free` too. Your second example is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're changing the value of the pointer, the address in memory that the pointer is pointing to:

Example 1:

```
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
                                  ^
                                  |
                                  pIntArray is here
```

Example 2:

```
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
 ^                                ^
 |                                |
 pIntArray is here                pCopy is here
```

You need to `delete[]` the exact pointer (this is because most C/C++ runtimes store the size of memory allocated at `ptr - 1 word`)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    cout << "integer[" << i << "] = " << *(pIntArray++) << endl;

}

cout << "deleting dynamic memory ..." << endl;

delete[] pIntArray;
```

You modify the value of `pIntArray` with the `++`, then you pass the *modified* value to `delete[]`. You need to pass to `delete[]` exactly the value returned by `new[]`.

Comment: I had in inclination that, that was the reason, but two quick questions: 1.Is that only regarding pointers returned from new. 2. So, as a rule if you are going to change the address of a pointer returned by new do you need to always cache it first so it can be properly deleted?

Comment: Do you need to always cache it first? I do not think so, however if you use a pointer as an array like in this problem then you might have to dereference the pointer to its initial value. Otherwise if you use a pointer as a pointer and not an array, then the current element that the pointer is pointing to will be delete to avoid memory leak. Whenever you use your pointer to point to another new value, the old value with its memory location that this pointer was pointing to cease to exist since you have freed that memory location.